# Can not call function using List<SuperType> parameter with List<SubType>

Tags: java, generics, collections

I created following function in Utils class:

```
public class Utils{
    public static String getUserIdCSVs(List<Serializable> voList) {
            StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
            if(voList != null){ 
                for(Serializable serializable :voList){
                    UserVO userVO = null;
                    if(serializable != null && serializable instanceof AdminVO){
                        userVO = ((AdminVO)serializable).getUserVO(); 
                    }
                    if(serializable != null && serializable instanceof UserVO){
                        userVO = (UserVO)serializable;
                    }
                    csv.append(userVO.getUserId()+",");
                }
            }
            return csv.toString();
        }
}
```

I can not call

using:

```
List<AdminVO> adminVoList = new ArrayList<AdminVO>
Utils.getUserIdCSVs(adminVoList);
```

OR using:

```
List<UserVO> userVoList = new ArrayList<UserVO>
Utils.getUserIdCSVs(userVoList);
```

The function compiles correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected: in Java, there is no covariance for generic types based on classes from the same hierarchy.

If you think about it, this makes sense. Consider this:

```
List<AdminVO> adminVoList = new ArrayList<AdminVO>();
Utils.addUser(adminVoList); // assume it expects ArrayList<Serializable>
```

Now `Utils.addUser` is free to add a `UserVO` (or anything else that's `Serializable`) to the list of admins, in violation of the type of the original list:

```
static addUser(List<Serializable> users) {
    users.add(new UserV0("I am not an admin!"));
}
```

However, since `users` inside `addUser` is the same as `adminVoList` outside it, you end up with non-admins in the list that is supposedly composed of admins.

To work with this limitation, simply declare your `adminVoList` as

```
List<Serializable> adminVoList = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
```

Comment: I understood the solution but what is meant by `there is no covariance for generic types based on classes from the same hierarchy`. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @LearnMore Other languages let you do things like that, with some limitations; the feature is called "generic type covariance". Here is a [link to an article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) that explains the details.

Answer (score 1):

`List<AdminVO>` is not a subclass of `List<Serializable>`.

Imagine it was:

```
List<AdminVO> list = new LinkedList<>();
List<Serializable> myList = list;
myList.add(new SomeConcreteSerializable()); 
//list contains an element which is not of type AdminVO!
```